# Not authorized to perform: lambda:GetFunction

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless, serverless-framework

I am trying to deploy lambda function with Serverless framework
I've added my ADMIN credentials in the aws cli
and I am getting this error message every time I try to deploy

> Warning: Not authorized to perform: lambda:GetFunction for at least one of the lambda functions. Deployment will not be skipped even if service files did not change.
>
> Error:
> CREATE_FAILED: HelloLambdaFunction (AWS::Lambda::Function)
> Resource handler returned message: "null (Service: Lambda, Status Code: 403, Request ID: ********)" (RequestToken: ********, HandlerErrorCode: GeneralServiceException)

I've also removed everything from my project and from the YML file and nothing worked

```
service: test
frameworkVersion: '3'
provider:   
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  iam:
    role:
      statements:
        - Effect: "Allow"
          Action:
            - lambda:*
            - lambda:InvokeFunction
            - lambda:GetFunction
            - lambda:GetFunctionConfiguration
          Resource: "*"

functions:
  hello:
    handler: handler.hello
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I tried to create a lambda function manually from the AWS website I found that I've no permission to view or create any lambda function
And after that I found that my account was suspended due to a behavior I've done that is not acceptable in AWS policy
I've followed the steps the support has sent me and then my account was back and everything worked fine

Answer (score 1):

Deployments default to us-east-1 region and used the default profile set on the machine where the serverless command is run. Perhaps you dont have permission to deploy is that region or serverless is using a different profile than intended. (e.g If i run serverless from an EC2 and login separately, it would still use the default profile, i.e the EC2 instance Profile.)

Can you update your `serverless.yml` file to include the region as well.

```
provider:   
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  region: <region_id>
  profile: profile name if not Default
```

Comment: i've added them and nothing worked